# ng-show not changing in jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I'm writing some jasmine tests for an angular directive that shows a spinner. My directive looks like:

```
define([
    "app",
    "spin"
], function(
    app,
    Spinner
    ){
    'use strict';

    return app
        .directive('processing', function() {

            return {
                restrict:'E',
                transclude: false,
                scope: {
                    show: '=show',
                    message: '=message'
                },

                templateUrl: 'directives/spin/processing.html',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    var spinner = new Spinner({
                        lines: 17, // The number of lines to draw
                        length: 40, // The length of each line
                        width: 10, // The line thickness
                        radius: 60, // The radius of the inner circle
                        corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
                        rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
                        direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
                        color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
                        speed: 1, // Rounds per second
                        trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
                        shadow: true, // Whether to render a shadow
                        hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
                        className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
                        zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
                        top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
                        left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
                    }).spin();
                    var loadingContainer = element[0].querySelectorAll('.processing-spinner-container')[0];
                    loadingContainer.appendChild(spinner.el);

                }
            };


        });
});
```

and my template looks like this:
`<div><div ng-show="show" class="processing-spinner-container"></div></div>`

Now, when I want to make a jasmine unit test, testing ng-show, I have something like this

```
           it('should be there when ngShow is true', inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
                $scope = $rootScope.$new();
                $scope.show = true;
                var element = $compile('<processing>\</processing>')($scope);
                $scope.$apply();
                var spinnerContainer = element[0].querySelector('.processing-spinner-container');
                expect(spinnerContainer.classList.contains('ng-hide')).toBe(false);
            }));
```

however, this test fails. It still has the `ng-hide` class even though I've set the $scope.show to true.

Comment: Did you run the digest? $scope.digest();